# Значение важности задания свойства position: relative для дочернего absolute

Tags: html, css

Есть элемент `a`, к которому нужно в `::after` по центру точку поместить. Просто для примера.
Во всех гайдах в Интернете, что я смотрел, везде писалось, что родителю нужно указать `position: relative`, а дочернему (в этом примере это `::after`) необходимо приписать `position: absolute`.
С абсолютом всё понятно, он служит для того, чтобы начать свое позиционирования относительно позиции родителя.
А зачем родителю указывать `relative`? Ведь `left` и `top` не применяются (и в тех примерах, что я смотрел, тоже).
Хотелось бы разобраться, так уж нужен этот `relative` родителю и почему, подскажите.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/8ov4g4c2/

Comment: @soledar10, благодарю, всё понял теперь.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы просто зададите элементу `position: absolute;`, но ничего не зададите больше, то он будет позиционироваться также, как и `static`. Его соседи справа могут под него залазить и всё.

`position: absolute;` ценен именно с точки зрения задания свойств `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom` относительно родителя с `position: relative;`. Его использование оправдано, если вы хотите чтобы элементы залазили друг на друга в зависимости от `z-index`.

Comment: а что если есть такая структура: див1, див2, див3. Каждый включен в другого по цепочке. У первого relative, а у остальных absolute.
Как поведет себя свойство, от кого наследуется? Какие-то свойства у каждого заданы свои.

Comment: @VostokSisters Это лучше на конкретном примере рассматривать. Для данного вопроса, я полагаю, я ответил довольно информативно.

Comment: @VostokSisters А также вам рекомендую просто пробовать, исследовать статьи и уже заданные вопросы по этому поводу, и если вдруг что-то будет неясно, тогда и задать новый вопрос.

Comment: а мне как раз конкретно не ясно, почему та структура, которую я описал, отображается некорректно в фаерфоксе, а в остальных (Опера и Хром) отображается так, как я задумывал.
Позиционирование идет черт знает от чего, а в других нормально.

Comment: @VostokSisters Верю вам, честное слово. Но просто вы задали *общий* вопрос, и получили *общий* ответ. Если вам надо конкретный вопрос, то, пожалуйста, *новый* *конкретный* вопрос. А это оставьте как есть, потому что он по-своему хорош и полезен. Если вам какой-то ответ оказался полезен или решил вас вопрос, то можете проголосовать за или отметить как принятый.